# Number Format issue in freemarker - Getting Roundoff after decimal nos

Tags: java, freemarker, smooks

I am using Freemarker template,I have a decimal value:

```
a = 23.65
```

I just want to retrieve above value as:

```
a = 23.6 <#-- Extract first number after decimal point -->
```

I have used number_format ex :

```
<#setting number_format="0.#">
```

But it rounded off the value after decimal point to `23.7`.
Could anybody know how to extract first number after decimal point without rounding off?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [extended formatting option](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#topic.extendedJavaDecimalFormat) in order to specify a `roundingMode`.
Please note, that you need at least FreeMarker 2.3.24 for these to work.

By default freemarker uses `halfEven` rounding mode. For your case, you can try to specify `down`

```
${(23.65)?string(",##0.0;; roundingMode=down")}
```

You can check this expression online [here](https://try.freemarker.apache.org/).